# How do I create an ordered list in Hoplon?

Tags: web-applications, hoplon

Given the list:

```
<ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
</ol>
```

How can I create the same in Hoplon script (i.e. in Hoplon syntax)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(ol
  (li :text "first")
  (li :text "second"))
```

You can find more examples [here](https://github.com/tailrecursion/hoplon-demos).